# How do I create a fixed color map in Seaborn/Matplotlib (min value = Red, max value = Green)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am attempting to create a fixed color map to use as a palette in a seaborn point plot. My current code is as follows:

```
        my_cmap2 = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ['red', 'orange', 'gold' ,'yellow', 'greenyellow', 'lime', 'green'])
        matplotlib.cm.register_cmap("mycolormap", my_cmap2)
        cpal = sns.color_palette("mycolormap", n_colors=10, desat=1)
        
        ax = sns.pointplot(x="Rank", y="Yld_Vol_Dr", data=df, hue="Rank", palette=cpal)
```

I need to fix the minimum value (rank) always to red and the max value (rank) to green. My current code works if I have 10 ranks exactly which is what I will have at most, but if I am missing any data (ex. rank 2) then I don't get the full color scale I require.

How do I set red/green as fixed min/max?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hue_order` can be used to force all hue values to be present (and set their order).

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

my_cmap2 = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ['red', 'orange', 'gold', 'yellow', 'greenyellow', 'lime', 'green'])
plt.cm.register_cmap("mycolormap", my_cmap2)
cpal = sns.color_palette("mycolormap", n_colors=10, desat=1)
rank = np.random.choice([1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10], 200)  # test with 2, 4 and 9 missing
y = np.random.uniform(0, 10, rank.shape)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 4))

sns.pointplot(x=rank, y=y, hue=rank, palette=cpal, ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title('without  hue_order')
ax1.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 1.05), loc='upper left')

sns.pointplot(x=rank, y=y, hue=rank, hue_order=range(1, 11), palette=cpal, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title('using hue_order')
ax2.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 1.05), loc='upper left')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: comparing example plots]

Comment: Thank you for the help!